# Place to define a new method

Tags: ruby

I am implementing a new method called `using`.

```
class Object
  def using(resource)
    begin
      yield if block_given?
    ensure
      resource.dispose
    end
  end
end
```

but in the book Metaprogramming Ruby, the right answer was written by reopening Kernel module instead of Object class. What are advantages using Kernel module before Object class?